# Unity: Stay logged in on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine

I am kinda new to Unity. I am currently developing my first game for IOS and Android. I am at the point where I want my users to sign up and log in. I'll store their data inside a mysql database. That works fine. However, I lack some basic knowledge on that procedure for mobile apps in general.

If a user signs up and logs in and closes the app, how do I handle his session? In games like Clash of clans, you basically sign up once and stay logged in forever with your mobile phone even if u delete the app and download it again.

How is that handled inside mobile apps by Unity? In PHP, I would simple use a session and/or cookies to achieve that. But as I said, I lack some basic knowledge on how that is done on mobile games.

Basically, I want to know on how to distinguish players by their IDs and make them sign up once with their phone and stay signed in forever, at least as long as they don't log out. How do I create these sessions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

in ios and android, android when you press the home button and ios when you press the circle button it is going to fire

```
 void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus) {
        paused = pauseStatus;
        //do your sign in and sign out work
    }
```

when it runs that method in your game and the user is out for a period of time usually the service of being signed in and out will sign out so you have to have a method to check if your service is signed in or not

```
isSignedIn();
```

using that in an if{} then you can automatically sign back in or not in the OnApplicationPause() method

for android if they press the back button

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){}
```

then that will end your app totally so when they open the app back up it will start from your initial loading screen then you can silently authenticate them into the sign on process, same for ios too if you are using

```
Application.Quit()
```

int your game

Comment: Hello!, thanks for your response. However, what do mean by "service of being signed in"? I mean, yeah, I can let users type in their username and password and check it on my msql server,  but how do I know if a session exists inside the game? It wouldn't make much sense to create a session/cookie inside my PHP script, would it? Kind regards

Comment: Thats completely upto you, however you plan to use your login

Comment: How is it done inside mobile games? How would you do it? I'm sorry but I am missing out on something.

Comment: From the info of what I put up is how I handle google play game services in apps, to make your own service from php I have no clue, I was just giving you a unity side basic rundown, sorry I cant help you with php I have no experience with it

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Remember : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Toggle tog;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("select"))
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("select") == 1)
            {
                tog.isOn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                tog.isOn = false;
            }

        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (tog.isOn == true)
        {

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("select", 1);
        }
        else
        {

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("select", 0);
        }

    }
}
```

it's Save toogle value so use playerperf to your username&password to keep me logge in